# MVC dynamic javascript with action call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Dynamic JavaScript on change event not firing I have my action result as follows

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Script = "<input type='text' name='myName' onchange='nameChange(this)' /><br/>" +
                "<script type='text/javascript'>function nameChange(d){" +
                "$('[name=myEmail]').val('');" +
                "$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '/Home/Search', data: '{name:d}', " +
                "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'html'," +
                "success: function(data) { $('[name=myEmail]').val(data.toString());            }        });" +
                "}</script>"
                + "<input type='text' name='myEmail' />";
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
```

I have my controller as follows

```
public ContentResult Search(string name)
        {
            return Content("hello@gmail.com");
        }
```

But the action url is not getting recognized can some one help me

cshtml

```
@if (ViewBag.Script != null)
{

    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Script)

}
```

Comment: That's not Javascript. Maybe you forgot to add the Typescript tag?

Comment: No typescript  jquery/javascript

Comment: The code you've shown is definitely not Javascript. Javascript has no types and no `public` or `private` or `void`.

Comment: I said MVC, i am binding it on the cshtml page

Comment: You haven't tagged correctly then. You MVC tag refers to the architectural pattern, not a specific implementation of it.

Comment: Why are you sending the script in this way rather than using a separate .js file? A separate file is simpler and easyer to write and debug through visual studio

Comment: I need to bind this dynamic way as per requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` you are defining that you will send `Json` with the `$.ajax` request but you are not. You should make a `Json` object by changing the `$.ajax data` to:

`data: JSON.stringify({name:d})`

You have also defined a POST transaction in your `$.ajax` so the Controller Action should be decorated with a `[HttpPost]` attribute:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Search(string name)
{
    return Content("hello@gmail.com");
}
```

Comment: Hi but I am not getting name as null for search function

Comment: Got it `d.value` gave me the expected result